# What is WOP in math or when $2 + 2 * 2$ is equal 8?

Tags: arithmetic

I know that this sounds dumb (I'm kind of math ignorant), but for past 30 years of my life I was more than sure that there is only one solution to this equation:

$2 + 2 * 2 = 6$

Until I was hit with "welcome screen" in [Mobi Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.android.calc&hl=en) asking me (?)... eee... what kind of math do I want to use in it:

[image]

and suggesting (?) that... in certain situations $2 + 2 * 2 = 8$ is true.

What is WOP or what am I missing here?

Comment: Well there are two interpretation of $2 + 2 \times 2$. One is $2 + (2 \times 2)$, the other one is $(2 + 2) \times 2$. Usually, it is interpreted as the first case since multiplication and division takes precedence over addition and subtraction. I think the calculator is asking you if you want to have the normal precedence rule or without it (so we will do the arithmetic operation from left to right).

Comment: Personally, I like to use posfix calculator (see [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Explanation)) because you don't to need type those parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can means "without operations priority", doing operations one by one from left to right.

Answer (score 4):

WOP is likely WithOutPriority, i.e. calculate all operations at the same priority, left-to-right: $2+2(=4)\times 2(=8)$.

Answer (score 1):

I can confidently say that $2 + 2 * 2 = 6$ is the correct solution. I think that the calculator has an option for those that do not want to use parenthesis, in which case it will do operations left to right.